# Best way to code and to connect two models in python

Tags: django, django-models

I have created a "quote" app and in my next phase I would like to create a dropdown list with my "contacts".
I'm only wondering what is the easiest, and best practices to create another class with the details of the contacts, or creating a new "app" to hold all the details of the contacts.

Comment: Opinion-based questions are generally not a good fit for SO

Answer (score 0):

If your details has `one-to-one` relation with contact you can use `OneToOneField` and if has `one-to-many` relation, you can use `OneToManyField`. for more information follow this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) and [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/).

with `select_related` for one-to-one and `prefetch_related` for one-to-many, you can join tables.

I don't think you need to create an app.